# destroy element event in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am searching for event that will execute when user change the partial view. Something like `$(window).unload()` event, but I need it only for a partial view - only element in the window changed.

Comment: You probably execute an ajax call or something to change the partial view. Why don't you put your code there ?

Comment: When you say partial view, are you referring to making the browser force reload when it gets shrank?